# Gravar um valor default dentro de determinada célula em C#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Estou fazendo uma aplicação console que faz a leitura de dados de uma planilha e compara com valores informados no banco. Existe um valor default, caso um campo desta planilha não esteja preenchido, preciso pegar o valor do banco e setar na planilha na célula que não foi preenchida. A minha dificuldade está sendo como setar este valor nesta célula. Consigo fazer em uma nova célula.

```
public class EscreverPlanilha {
    public void EscreveValorDefault(Campo campo, string column) {
        var str = new StringBuilder();
        str.Append(campo.ValorDefault);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você está acessando a planilha? através do open xml?

Comment: Estou utilizando o StreamReader <br>   List<string> lista = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(caminho))
                {

                    string linha = null;


                    while ((linha = rd.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        lista.Add(linha.ToString());

                    }

                    rd.Close();
                    rd.Dispose();

                    return lista;


                }
            }

Comment: Acho melhor utilizar o Open XML. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/hh298534.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca Open XML para setar valor nas células.
Veja em https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/hh298534.aspx como fazer.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada!